# Web components - what's the execution context?

Tags: html, web-component

I'm could not find anywhere answer to question that poped out to me: if web components are able to create a new code execution context where code runs on it's own thread or do those components share the host execution context?

**Does running code that is blocking main thread in web component would block the host thread also?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does running code that is blocking main thread in web component would block the host thread also?

The execution context is a call stack composed of custom element queues:

> To facilitate invoking callbacks, each unit of related similar-origin browsing contexts has a processing stack, which is initially empty. Each item in the stack is an element queue, which is initially empty as well. Each item in the element queue is a custom element.

**References**

- [Custom Elements Specification](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/)
- [Web Components Status Meeting Notes](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebComponentsStatusMeetingNotes)
- [Web Components, Angular, Polymer and React](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/web-components-angular-polymer-and-react/)

Comment: Do I understand correct - since it queues callbacks - it's the same context for all elements and if I block somewhere it will block the main thread as well?

Comment: @VytautasButkus You are correct. Web Components follow the same [context rules](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context) as other HTML5 elements.